# How to share Docker image from Private Github package

Tags: docker, github

I built an image docker and push it (manually) to my Github packages (private package) then I pull it and run it and it works fine, now I want to share this image with a friend who wants to run it on his PC, I gave him the pull command but he got the following error: `docker pull "url" Error response from demon : Head unauthorized`
I know it is an authentication issue but since im new to GitHub package I don't know what I have to do to share the image correctly.

any idea about this issue please?

Answer (score -1):

name: Publish Docker image

on:
release:
types: [published]

jobs:
push_to_registry:
name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Check out the repo
uses: actions/checkout@v3

```
  - name: Log in to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
  
  - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
    id: meta
    uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
    with:
      images: my-docker-hub-namespace/my-docker-hub-repository
  
  - name: Build and push Docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
    with:
      context: .
      push: true
      tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
      labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }
```

Comment: REDY im not using github workflows i  push and pull manually